# Stored procedures with two input dates - is there any way to load before query - BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am being asked to run a query everyday and would like to have it automated but the stored procedure requires me to update the start and end dates.

Format is `yyyymmdd` (example: `'20221220'`, `'20221221'`)

```
call A.procedure ('startdate', 'enddate');
```

I've tried declaring or setting date values - with no success.

Comment: What's your error? to create the procedure? to invoke it? to schedule it?

Comment: to schedule / invoke with a date automatically entered. I was hoping to set a date varaibel = today()  ... but does this need to be in the procedure query or before it?

Comment: When you schedule a  call, the parameter are statics. You can imagine customizing your procedure to detect special word (like TODAY, NOW, YESTERDAY), instead of date in string format. Or you need to invoke first a processing component (Cloud FUnctions, Cloud RUn, App ENgine,...) that generate/customize the parameters, and then invoke the procedure